# Mlxtend apriori not founding dtypes for sparse matrix

Tags: python, pandas, numpy, apriori, mlxtend

I've been trying to use an sparse matrix for association rule mining but it keeps throwing `AttributeError: dtypes not found`. I know what the Error means, but I haven't been able to solve it. This is what I have:

```
import pandas as pd
import scipy
from mlxtend.frequent_patterns import fpgrowth
from mlxtend.frequent_patterns import apriori, association_rules

test_data = pd.read_csv('.../test_data.csv')

test_data = pd.DataFrame(test_data, dtype = bool)
sparse_df = scipy.sparse.csr_matrix(test_data.values)
sparse_df
```

**Outcome:**

```
 <1000x10 sparse matrix of type '<class 'numpy.bool_'>'
    with 1257 stored elements in Compressed Sparse Row format>
```

Until here everything is good and working, but when I run the next chunk, it pops the error.

```
apriori(sparse_df, min_support = 0.3, use_colnames = True, verbose = 1)
```

I've checked other 'solutions' to the problem in other questions asked but none have worked for me.

**Whole ERROR**

```
---------------------------------------------------------------------------
AttributeError                            Traceback (most recent call last)
<ipython-input-259-ac3b4693270b> in <module>
----> 1 apriori(sparse_df, min_support = 0.3, use_colnames = True, verbose = 1)

~\anaconda3\lib\site-packages\mlxtend\frequent_patterns\apriori.py in apriori(df, min_support, use_colnames, max_len, verbose, low_memory)
    236                          'Got %s.' % min_support)
    237 
--> 238     fpc.valid_input_check(df)
    239 
    240     if hasattr(df, "sparse"):

~\anaconda3\lib\site-packages\mlxtend\frequent_patterns\fpcommon.py in valid_input_check(df)
     98 
     99     # Fast path: if all columns are boolean, there is nothing to checks
--> 100     all_bools = df.dtypes.apply(pd.api.types.is_bool_dtype).all()
    101     if not all_bools:
    102         # Pandas is much slower than numpy, so use np.where on Numpy arrays

~\anaconda3\lib\site-packages\scipy\sparse\base.py in __getattr__(self, attr)
    685             return self.getnnz()
    686         else:
--> 687             raise AttributeError(attr + " not found")
    688 
    689     def transpose(self, axes=None, copy=False):

AttributeError: dtypes not found
```

Comment: I should ask for the whole error - including traceback. But while I know `scipy.sparse` I have no idea what `mlxtend` is, nor what it expects.

Comment: I updated the post with the whole error

Comment: It's checking if the argument is "valid", The `df.dtypes.apply` clearly assumes `df` is a dataframe.  Only a frame as a `dtypes` attribute.  `numpy` array and `scipy.sparse/matrix` have a `dtype` attribute.  So unless there's some other parameter or trick, this `apriori` method cannot use `scipy.sparse`.  What gave you the idea that it did?

Comment: Looking at the github code, it is looking for a dataframe, with optional `sparse` attribute.  If available it does its own sparse matrix conversion.  You don't do that beforehand.

Comment: nothing in particular, I just needed a way to make the df a sparse matrix so the algorithm could run faster because mlxtend documentation says so.

Comment: I'll go for it and run it without sparsing the matrix beforehand, thanks!